# jQuery's load function, other JS doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I'm using jQuery's load function to load the content of link when it's clicked, and all is working great apart from the JavaScript within the pages.

I'm guessing this is because it's just not getting applied to the new content.
I had a look at the `$.getScript` function but I don't fully understand it, and what I've tried doesn't work.

The JavaScript I've created so far:

```
var dest = new Array(4);
dest[0] = window.location.href;
dest[1] = 'content/index.php';
dest[2] = 'content/slideshow.php';
dest[3] = 'content/scaffold.php';
dest[4] = 'content/elements.php';
dest[7] = 'content/404.php';

function loadcontent(d, b, p, newclass) {
var stateObj = { foo: p };
if (b == 'yes') {
    $('#bgdiv').html('<img id="bg" src="images/bg_bokeh.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />');
} else {
    $('#bgdiv').html('');
}
document.body.className = newclass;
if (dest[d] == 'content/slideshow.php') {
    $.getScript('js/external-slideshow.js');
}

$.getScript('js/scripts.js');
$.getScript('js/plugins.js');
$.getScript('js/modernizr.js');

$('#page-content').load(dest[d]);

    history.pushState(stateObj, p, p);
}
```

And the code I use for my links:

```
<a href="javascript:loadcontent('3', 'yes', 'about.php', 'page page-id-269 page-template-default');">about</a>
```

I have onload functions in the 3 js files listed above (scripts, plugins, modernizr), do they not get executed again with the `$.getScript` function? Or do I have to find another way to reload the onload functions?

Thanks

**Edit**
Phil's answer worked. I just had the getScript call in the wrong place. Oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` functions in the includes JS files don't get executed when they're loaded because an `onload` event only happens when the page (and all the content defined in the HTML in the page) have loaded. According to the [jQuery docs for $.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) you can pass a function as a second parameter to $.getScript that gets executed when the file is loaded; you can either do in that what you have in the `onload` in the other files, or have that function call a function in the included file.

Comment: I have multiple $(window).load functions, so because of this I can't call each function. Is there any way of having it 'rerun' the JS file? Or would I in fact be better off creating an XMLHTTPRequest? Would that run the the JS code again?

Comment: One thing you could do is to use named functions in your other JS files, and use $(window).load(namedFunction) [or $(namedFunction) ], and then use that named function as the second parameter to $.getScript [so you'd have $.getScript(url, namedFunction) ].

Comment: That'd fix a lot of my problems however I'm using jQuery and a few other JS plugins so I don't think I'd be able to turn them all into named functions